# Adding DelegatingHandler to Owin OAuthAuthorizationServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorization, owin

I have created a custom `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` which has the follow method:

```
override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)  
override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)  
override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
```

I would like to add a custom `DelegatingHandler` to block access based on IP.
But I can't find any place to register the handler.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        List<DelegatingHandler> ipApi = new List<DelegatingHandler>();
        ipApi.Add(new CheckIpMessageHandler());
        var routeIpHandlers = HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpControllerDispatcher(config), ipApi);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            handler: routeIpHandlers
        );
    }
}
```

This doesn't register the handler into the pipeline.
Thanks

Comment: Can't you create an IAuthorizationFilter and add it globally?

Comment: ActionFilters are an MVC/WebAPI concept. I think the OAuth2 middleware (OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider) intercepts the request before even reaching the upper level frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

If feasible, you can apply white- /blacklisting of IP -addresses e.g. when intercepting requests in your `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`'s implementation by overriding `ValidateTokenRequest` -method. Either way, you could refactor your current delegating handler into a OWIN middleware component that gets executed before hitting any subsequent layers or in your provider - or reuse with applicable parts within the forementioned provider.

Regarding the OWIN middleware, my search's very first hit and a repo at GitHub was project called HttpTrackingMiddleware: 
https://github.com/springcomp/HttpTrackingMiddleware , which looks promising.

All in all, you have several options here: OWIN middleware, provider or pretty much try at your last resort registering your handler at:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new CheckIpMessageHandler());
```

Good luck!